# Ruby on Rails FedEx gem with Zebra thermal label printer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using this gem - https://github.com/jazminschroeder/fedex - to connect to the FedEx shipping API. Right now I'm able to successfully create a shipping label as a full-page PDF, however I'm having issues getting it to create a label that's formatting to print with a Zebra ZP500 thermal printer for labels:

```
fedex.label( 
            ..., 
            :label_specifications => LABEL_SPECS 
           )

LABEL_SPECS = { :label_format_type => "COMMON2D", :image_type => "ZPLII", :label_stock_type => "STOCK_4X6" }
```

I've tried basically all the combinations for image_type, label_format_type, and label_stock_type and yet they always come out formatted incorrectly or sized way too small on the thermal printer. I've also tried using the minimagick gem to save the PDF as an image and write it to a new file and I still keep getting the same result:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(temp_file.path.to_s)
image.format "png"
image.density '300'
image.rotate '-90'
image.crop('1300X1820+90+90')
image.write (label.file_name.to_s + ".png")
```

and:

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new(label.file_name)
file = File.open(label.file_name)
temp_file.write file.read

image1 = MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
  convert.density '300'
  convert.rotate '-90'
  convert.background 'white'
  convert.format 'png'
  convert.crop('1300X1820+90+90')
  convert << temp_file.path
end
```

Has anyone had success using this gem for FedEx shipping in combination with a thermal printer to print shipping labels? Thanks

Comment: This may be too late but what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is with your printer scaling, not how the label is being generated.